# How to get demangled function name using regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have list of demangled-function names like `_Z6__comp7StudentS_`
`_Z4SortiSt6vectorI7StudentSaIS0_EE`. I read wiki and found out that it follows some sort of defined structure. _Z is mangled Symbol followed by a number and then the function name of that length.

So I wanted to retrieve that function name using regex. I only come close to `_Z(?:\d)(?<function_name>[a-z_A-Z]){\1}`. But referring \1 won't work because its string, right? Is there a single regex pattern solution to this.

Comment: What exactly should be the result for the examples you have shown?

Comment: @mkrieger1 "__comp" for the first one and "Sort" for the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 2 capture groups, and get the part of the string using the position of capture group 2

```
import re

pattern = r"_Z(\d+)([a-z_A-Z]+)"
s = "_Z4SortiSt6vectorI7StudentSaIS0_EE"
m = re.search(pattern, s)

if m:
    print(m.group(2)[0: int(m.group(1))])
```

Output

```
Sort
```

Using `_Z6__comp7StudentS_` will return `__comp`